# Creating RSA PublicKey from bytes with Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++

Yesterday I setup a Go server which generates a RSA Key and then sends it to my C++ client in `PKCS#1, ASN.1 DER` form. (https://godoc.org/crypto/x509#MarshalPKCS1PublicKey)

Today I've tried a bunch of things but none felt right. After finally being able to somewhat, possibly, get the bytes into a `BufferedTransformation` to use `PEM_Load` I encoded the bytes into Base64 and added header and footer text manually. Then I ran into "BER decode error" and now I'm stuck and not sure if what I've created is even a valid key.

Here's what I feed it for example:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAvXlhiyxoyUob149+8PpKe5oFKqFuz84DRG+jlFdsvgGi+6PTMYYtupnn/1Sn
BXQRoTvI7O9SDSxOFKvQki3jv6/qh8aXPM5rX6GesHxzVKaMNeiJPsqmbFCzv0KUrO5Z6ERE
aadxUl8M6pAE5uH5aaI/AJvRs08xiUICzQ19Pml97YdzwwJ0uxhPqIHok3oskG76myBkhB6H
kIErTwINA8zSQIfIFIPSftkc6/H/woqmZIr6aIsO7gACx7V/EwyXsEyX1DN3nbcJOb3DCCFF
fUQYUrdMugoNmNHJ+iCw6wl+V1le/b7T57xUhBIRuMNiXzjqu5XW3fRJH3eyQWELjQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and here's the full code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cryptopp/pem.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/base64.h>
#include <cryptopp/dsa.h>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace CryptoPP;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    RSA::PrivateKey rsa_private;
    AutoSeededRandomPool random;

    rsa_private.GenerateRandomWithKeySize( random, 2048 );
    auto rsa_public = RSA::PublicKey( rsa_private );

    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::socket s( io_context );
        tcp::resolver resolver( io_context );
        boost::asio::connect( s, resolver.resolve( "127.0.0.1", "9999" ));

        int headersize;
        size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read( s,
            boost::asio::buffer( &headersize, sizeof(headersize ) ) );

        printf( "Got header with size %i\n", headersize );

        std::vector<CryptoPP::byte> RSA_PUB(headersize);
        size_t read_size = boost::asio::read( s,
            boost::asio::buffer( RSA_PUB.data(), headersize ) );
        RSA::PublicKey testpub;

        Base64Encoder encoder;
        encoder.Put( RSA_PUB.data( ), RSA_PUB.size( ) );
        encoder.MessageEnd( );

        std::string encoded;
        auto encoded_size = encoder.MaxRetrievable( );
        if ( encoded_size ) {
            encoded.resize( encoded_size );
            encoder.Get( ( byte* )&encoded[ 0 ], encoded.size( ) );
        }

        encoded.insert( 0, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" );
        encoded.append( "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" );

        
        //ArraySource( RSA_PUB.data( ), RSA_PUB.size( ), true );
        CryptoPP::ByteQueue test;
        test.Put( (byte*)encoded.data( ), encoded.size( ) );
        test.MessageEnd( );

        
        PEM_Load( test, testpub );
        //std::cout.write( RSA_PUB.data( ), RSA_PUB.size( ) );

    } catch ( std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what( ) << "\n";
    }
    std::cin.get( );
    return 0;
}
```

Update:
Today I went further and saved generated key into file from Crypto++ then saved the one generated from Go down too and compared them:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Ktr.png)
and based of this I can see that the format is quite similar so I'm not too far off atleast. My next step now is to find and use a software to verify the format since I've seen it mentioned in the past.

Update 2:
It's pretty obvious that `MarshalPKCS1PublicKey` leaves out what i'd describe as a header from the data and goes straight to the actual value. Not sure how to solve this. Asking around in the Go discord.

Comment: If you change the anchor in your example to `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` (rather than just 'public key') then `openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in` will accept it. But no idea about CryptoPP.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the reply!. It did accept it the same way as before. Had to add `END RSA PUBLIC KEY` as well but unfortunately still `BER decode error`.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the key using `BERDecodePublicKey` from `PublicKey` worked! The way I was trying to load it expected full X.509 format. To get the Crypto++ bytes in same format I would use `DEREncodePublicKey`.